# Does MemoryStream Copy on construction?

Tags: c#

When you construct a MemoryStream from a byte array, does the stream make its own copy? If, so is this a performance concern in a high performance scenario, when compared to just reading the bytes from the original array directly?

Comment: The source code should be the first place to look for: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,85

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Not really. The reference source code tells you the implementation details right now, but not the _contract_. Implementation details can (and do) change between versions of .NET.

Comment: @Luaan Of course it is. You need to have at least an idea. The contract can also change, so I don't see the point

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm not saying it's not a useful tool. I'm just saying it shouldn't be your first port of call, and shouldn't be taken as part of the contract. If you think implementation details are more reliable than contracts, that's all fine and dandy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be explicitly mentioned in the documentation, but keep in mind that you can use `MemoryStream` to modify an existing `byte[]`. That wouldn't make any sense if the byte array was copied.

Referring to .NET Reference Source, no copy is made on the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

From expirience I can say, that it does not copy the array. 
Be aware though, that **you are unable to resize the memory stream**, when using an array in the constructor.