# Why does BitmapImage use so much more memory when using MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to use memory stream because I load image from a database.
When I use file stream, just to compare, footprint of the app is consistent with
1x size of uncompressed image. But if I use memory stream, memory
usage is more like 3x.
I used 200MB of png images (4 images) and the app took 1GB of ram.

Is there a way to reduce memory usage?

```
private BitmapImage readfromdsk(string s)
        {

            var photo2f = File.Open(s, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            byte[] b = null;
            photo2f.Read(b=new byte[photo2f.Length], 0, (int)photo2f.Length);

            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b))
            {

                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;   //// lot of memory allocated on this line
                bitmapImage.EndInit();
            }

            b = null;
            photo2f.Dispose();

            return bitmapImage;
        }
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the images?

Comment: The dimensions are: 5652x6224, 3748x6800, 3832x2756, 4440x3084
Uncompressed size is: 242 MB

Comment: Why don't you pass it through directly `bitmapImage.StreamSource = photo2f ;`

Comment: That is the case when everything is OK. But the DB comunicates trough memory streams.

Comment: As a note, a much simpler way to read the image buffer would be `byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(s);`

Comment: It is perhaps a bad idea in the first place to store large binary objects like these image buffers in a database.

Comment: Yes but I want file stream.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that `BitmapImage` is creating its own copy of the pixels that it owns and manages.

In the file stream version, it can read the file in small blocks (e.g. 4kb at a time).  So, in this example, it will wind up using (4kb + uncompressed bitmap size) memory.

In your memory stream version, you first read the entire file into memory.  So it winds up being (file size + uncompressed bitmap size).  `BitmapImage` doesn't use your byte array directly.  It still "streams" it a chunk at a time.

If you want to reduce memory when reading form you DB, you'd need to build a streaming class (that implements `System.IO.Stream`) that reads from your database a chunk at a time.

Last thing to consider: This may or may not be an issue at all.  The GC will recover the memory used by the byte array, so the increase in memory usage is only temporary.

Comment: I use visual studio performance profiler, gc does nothing. Also everything should be cleared (except bitmapImage.StreamSource because I use cache). File stream , memory stream and bytes are all gone.  Also I will look into streaming class, thanks.

Comment: You forgot that stream need to grow first when it filled up - that will properly match OP's observations of 3x (stream's memory usage is roughly 1.5-2x of the data size, and bitmaps itself is 1x resulting in at least 2.5-3x size range of allocated virtual memory that OP is likely looking at... ).

Comment: Alexei, great point, I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Actually, upon checking, it looks like the memory stream uses the byte array directly instead of copying to its own, so I'm not sure this is a contributing factor.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52482122/does-memorystream-copy-on-construction

Comment: @OzSolomon For your understanding, the actual problem is that a MemoryStream never releases its reference to the byte array that you pass on construction, and the BitmapImage keeps a reference to the MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in

[.NET Memory issues loading ~40 images, memory not reclaimed, potentially due to LOH fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6271891/1136211)

a `MemoryStream` seems to keep a reference to the byte array that you pass on construction even after it was disposed of. This is a problem because a `BitmapImage` also keeps a reference to its `StreamSource`, so the original input byte array is never released.

To avoid this, you can use an additional `BufferedStream`, which releases the reference to its source stream when it is disposed of.

```
public BitmapSource LoadBitmap(MemoryStream memoryStream)
{
    using (var bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(memoryStream))
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmap.StreamSource = bufferedStream;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        bitmap.Freeze();
        return bitmap;
    }
}

public BitmapSource LoadBitmap(string path)
{
    var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        return LoadBitmap(memoryStream);
    }
}
```